# Python 3 import precedence with __init__.py

Tags: python, python-3.x

Given the following (notice `test` which by mistake shadows built in `test` package, which I should have named it `tests`, we will come back to this later in the question)

```
├── test
│   └── test_request_billing_id.py
└── requets_billing_id.py
```

when in Python shell, try to run `from test import test_request_billing_id` 
it gives `ImportError: cannot import name 'test_request_billing_id'`, which is trying to import the built-in `test` package instead of my own `test` folder.

This can be verified by running this **valid** import

`from test import support`

**Question 1:**

Given Python3 allows [implicit namespace packages](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/), which means my `test` folder is also a package, I guess the built in `test` package has higher priority than my own `test` package?

**Question 2:**

I created `__init__.py` inside my own `test` folder as below:

```
├── test
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── test_request_billing_id.py
└── requets_billing_id.py
```

and ran the same import statement again, it worked fine.

`from test import test_request_billing_id`

Shadowing built-in `test` be verified by running this **invalid** import

`from test import support` gives error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'support'`

This seems to me that having `__init__.py` tells python interpreter to make my `test` shadows the built-in `test` package.

Could someone please explain this or is this documented anywhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, packages with an `__init__.py` take precedence. This is explained in [this section](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0420/#specification) of the PEP:

> During import processing, the import machinery will continue to
>   iterate over each directory in the parent path as it does in Python
>   3.2. While looking for a module or package named "foo", for each directory in the parent path:
>
> - If `<directory>/foo/__init__.py` is found, a regular package is imported and returned.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo.{py,pyc,so,pyd}` is found, a module is imported and returned. The exact list of extension varies by platform
>     and whether the -O flag is specified. The list here is representative.
> - If not, but `<directory>/foo` is found and is a directory, it is recorded and the scan continues with the next directory in the parent
>     path.
> - Otherwise the scan continues with the next directory in the parent path.

If any namespace packages are encountered during the search process, they're "recorded" and the search continues. If a package containing an `__init__.py` is found later, the "recorded" namespace packages are discarded and the package with `__init__.py` is imported instead.

This is exactly what happens when your `test` package has no `__init__.py` - the `test` package in the standard library *does* have an `__init__.py`, so it takes precedence over your namespace `test` package.

Comment: Thanks that answers for question 2, can you pls try answering question 1 as well? Does it mean the built-in `test` package has `__init__` which will overtakes my `test` folder?

Comment: Enter the repl with '-v' flag for verbose and you should find your answer (you should see some lines like "possible namespace for /path/to/test").

Comment: @JamesLin I thought I already did. I've added a paragraph about it though. It's because the `test` package from the stdlib has an `__init__.py`, which makes it take precedence over your `test` package.

Comment: I think the part he's missing is that user package is still seen first, but since stdlib is not a namespace package, yours doesn't get to "contribute".